# Change colors in stacked barplot from dataframe.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I need to be able to change the colors of each bar of this stacked bar plot:

[image]

The code currently is:

```
my_colors = [(x/10.0, x/20.0, 0.75) for x in range(len(df))] 
ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,color = my_colors,alpha = 0.8,width = 0.7)
```

The Dataframe has multiple columns with two rows for each column.

How does the my_colors List have to like like to change the color for each part of the barplot?

Comment: Note that in your case `len(df)` is 2 as there are only two rows. `len(df.columns)` would be 11. The two colors (0/10.0, 0/20.0, 0.75) and (1/10.0, 1/20.0, 0.75) look very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plot bars from multiple columns (or rows and use the transpose .T), pandas will assign different colors to each column. So only 2 different colors in your case. The first two elements of your color list will be used.

If you need individual colors for each bar, you need to plot two times. The second time use the other as the bottom.

Some example code to show how it could work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

d = {a: [random.randint(2, 5), random.randint(3, 7)] for a in list('abcdefghij')}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
my_colors0 = [plt.cm.plasma(i / len(df.columns) / 2 + 0.5) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
ax = df.T[0].plot(kind='bar', color=my_colors0, width=0.7)
my_colors1 = [plt.cm.plasma(i / len(df.columns) / 2) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
ax = df.T[1].plot(kind='bar', bottom=df.T[0], color=my_colors1, width=0.7, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question?